# Save results of exists query to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to save result of this `EXISTS` query into a variable:

```
DECLARE @max_date DATETIME2
DECLARE @DatabaseSchema VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DatabaseSchema = 'SALES_MART'
SET @max_date = CASE 
                   WHEN EXISTS(SELECT MAX(SaleDate)
                               FROM  @DatabaseSchema.SalesReport
                               WHERE Categoryname = 'Asia')
                      THEN (SELECT MAX(SaleDate)
                            FROM  @DatabaseSchema.SalesReport
                            WHERE Categoryname = 'Asia')
                      ELSE GETDATE()
                END

EXEC @max_date
```

When I execute it, I got an error

> invalid column name  @DatabaseName.SalesReport

The reason for the error is SQL Server doesn't accept a variable after `FROM`.

I googled and tried to removed 'CASE WHEN' but it still doesn't work.
Can you please help me with this query? How should I edit it?

This is my test table:

```
CREATE SCHEMA SALES_MART;

CREATE TABLE SALES_MART.SalesReport  
( 
     id INT,
     SaleDate DATETIME2,
     sales INT,
     Categoryname VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO SALES_MART.SalesReport  
VALUES (1, '1905-07-08 00:00:00.000', 50, 'Asia'),
       (2, '1905-07-08 00:00:00.000', 90, 'Asia'),
       (3, '1905-07-08 00:00:00.000', 100, 'EU');
```

Comment: Ever heard of dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using SSMS as your IDE you could simply enable [Sql Command Mode](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2311/using-the-ssms-query-editor-in-sqlcmd-mode/) and then you can have a dynamic schema value. Try the following code:

```
:SetVar DatabaseSchema "SALES_MART"

CREATE SCHEMA $(DatabaseSchema);
GO

CREATE TABLE $(DatabaseSchema).SalesReport  
( 
     id INT,
     SaleDate DATETIME2,
     sales INT,
     Categoryname VARCHAR(100)
);
GO

INSERT INTO $(DatabaseSchema).SalesReport  
VALUES (1, '1905-07-08 00:00:00.000', 50, 'Asia'),
       (2, '1905-07-08 00:00:00.000', 90, 'Asia'),
       (3, '1905-07-08 00:00:00.000', 100, 'EU');

DECLARE @max_date DATETIME2

SET @max_date = CASE 
                   WHEN EXISTS(SELECT MAX(SaleDate)
                               FROM  $(DatabaseSchema).SalesReport
                               WHERE Categoryname = 'Asia')
                      THEN (SELECT MAX(SaleDate)
                            FROM  $(DatabaseSchema).SalesReport
                            WHERE Categoryname = 'Asia')
                      ELSE GETDATE()
                END

PRINT @max_date

-- Clean up
DROP TABLE $(DatabaseSchema).SalesReport;
GO

DROP SCHEMA $(DatabaseSchema);
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code corrected, which stores the result in variable @max_date 
The last select is for displaying the result

```
    CREATE SCHEMA SALES_MART;
    go
    create table SALES_MART.SaleReport  (id int,SaleDate datetime2,sales int,Categoryname varchar(100));
    INSERT INTO SALES_MART.SaleReport  
    VALUES
    (1,'1905-07-08 00:00:00.000',50,'Asia'),
    (2,'1905-07-08 00:00:00.000',90,'Asia'),
    (3,'1905-07-08 00:00:00.000',100,'EU');


     Declare @max_date  datetime2
     Declare @DatabaseSchema varchar(max)


        SElect   @max_date=CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT max(SaleDate)
                                            FROM  SALES_MART.SaleReport 
                                            WHERE Categoryname = 'Asia')
                             THEN (SELECT max(SaleDate)
                                            FROM  SALES_MART.SaleReport 
                                            WHERE Categoryname = 'Asia' )
                            ELSE getdate()  END

    select @max_date [result in varaiable]


[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImC1o.png







**ANOTHER SOLUTION WITH DYNAMIC SCRIPT**
This solution can be used for many schemas, it inserts the result (with the schema name and max date) in Tbale mytable


CREATE SCHEMA SALES_MART;
go
create table SALES_MART.SaleReport  (id int,SaleDate datetime2,sales int,Categoryname varchar(100));
INSERT INTO SALES_MART.SaleReport  
VALUES
(1,'1905-07-08 00:00:00.000',50,'Asia'),
(2,'1905-07-08 00:00:00.000',90,'Asia'),
(3,'1905-07-08 00:00:00.000',100,'EU');


 Declare @max_date  datetime2
 Declare @DatabaseSchema varchar(max)
 set @DatabaseSchema='SALES_MART'
 declare @script as varchar(max)

 create table mytable(myschema varchar(50),maxdate date)
 delete from mytable
 set @script='
    insert into mytable (myschema,maxdate)
    select '''+@DatabaseSchema+''',
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT max(SaleDate)
                                        FROM  '+@DatabaseSchema+'.SaleReport 
                                        WHERE Categoryname = ''Asia'')
                         THEN (SELECT max(SaleDate)
                                        FROM  SALES_MART.SaleReport 
                                        WHERE Categoryname = ''Asia'' )
                        ELSE getdate()  END'

exec(@script)

select * from mytable
```

Comment: Thankyou. But i want to use variable for databaseSchema after FROM clause because i want to make the Query dynamic

Comment: In such case, you have to use dynamic script, store the script in a variable and execute it

Comment: Thanks Kemal, i will see it

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use a parameter for your schema name, then you'll need to use dynamic SQL. It converts your string into a query, so you can concatenate your string parameter with a string query you've written. You can output the value to a parameter as well.

I've simplified your query using coalesce. It takes the first value if not NULL and the second if the first is NULL

```
Declare @DatabaseSchema varchar(max)
SET @DatabaseSchema ='SALES_MART'
DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT COALESCE((SELECT max(SaleDate) FROM '+ @DatabaseSchema + '.SalesReport WHERE Categoryname = ''Asia''), GETDATE())' 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query, N'@Output DATETIME OUT', @MaxDate OUT
PRINT @MaxDate
```

Comment: Thanks Tim . I have read a lot about dynamic query with sp executesql but till now i am confusing about how to use it. In your query above can you please explain why you set the output like this: N'@Output DATETIME OUT', @MaxDate OUT . I really don’t understand

Comment: sp_executesql allows you to output values from the query you execute. You can have as many pairs as you want. The first params (Output in this case) exist in the context of the query, so you add them as one nvarchar (hence the N at the beginning) and comma separate the parameters inside that string, along with their types. MaxDate exists in your main context since you declared it at the beginning. By pairing it with output, you set the value to a variable existing in the context you need

Comment: Dynamic SQL is dangerous, because it renders your inputs unsanitary, so you should never use it with your web projects. A parameterized query doesn't just string replace as is being done in the dynamic SQL. The optimizer establishes the query first and then only allows parameters where they can be compared literally. This way the parameter cannot extend the query and introduce anything malicious. Dynamic SQL just takes your whole string and converts into a query, so if a param adds anything malicious that alters the purpose of the query, it will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

variables are not allowed in server, schema, and table names, and also a couple of other places as well (such as in ALTER, CREATE, DROP ..etc).

In your case, you're trying to use it in schema name, to use it like this, you will have two options.

**Option 1:**

Define each select statement and use IF to get the select statement you want based on the variable input.

Example :

```
DECLARE
    @max_date       DATETIME2
,   @DatabaseSchema VARCHAR(max) = 'SALES_MART'

SET @max_date = CASE @DatabaseSchema
                    WHEN 'SALES_MART'       THEN (SELECT MAX(SaleDate) FROM SALES_MART.SalesReport WHERE Categoryname = 'Asia')
                    WHEN 'SALES_MART_TWO'   THEN (SELECT MAX(SaleDate) FROM SALES_MART_TWO.SalesReport WHERE Categoryname = 'Asia')
                    ELSE GETDATE()
                END 

SET @max_date = CASE WHEN @max_date IS NULL THEN GETDATE() ELSE @max_date END -- You can replace it with ISNULL(@max_date, GETDATE()) 

SELECT @max_date
```

**Option 2** (Not always recommanded as it has its own risks):

Use daynamic sql instead.

```
DECLARE
    @max_date       DATETIME2
,   @DatabaseSchema VARCHAR(max) = 'SALES_MART'
,   @sql            VARCHAR(max) = ''

    SET @sql = 'ISNULL( (SELECT MAX(SaleDate) FROM @DatabaseSchema.SalesReport WHERE Categoryname = ''Asia''), GETDATE())'

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@DatabaseSchema',  @DatabaseSchema)

    EXEC (@sql)
```